# OpenCart 2.1 - Get customer First name in header.tpl

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Adds: `$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();` in `header.php`

You may be something:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
```

Displays the name eg in header.tpl: `<?php echo $customer_firstname ?>`

Login to your store manager: go to extensions, modifications and upgrade (button top right).

Ready!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two header.tpl files inside OpenCart project. I think you are editing header.tpl inside public_html/catalog/controller/common/header.tpl ,so there is nothing will solve your problem editing this file.

go to the other location where second header.tpl file located. you can find it inside public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.tpl . in there you can get values by adding these,

```
    $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
    $data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
```

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

get customer information:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($this->customer->getId());
        $data['customer_firstname'] = $customer_info['firstname'];
```

Comment: And try does not work, that file and what part should I put this code?

Comment: Edit the question with what I suggest, if I am not putting the code where it is.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced post uses

```
$data['customer_firstname']
```

You should put your variable in the $data-Array to pass it to the template...

Comment: You could better explain this please.

Comment: Please read the linked thread you mentioned and look at the accepted answer. They use "$data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();" and I just can assume that $data is passed to the template solely. Inside the .TPL you can access the values without pointing to $data.

Comment: This page is meant to help you solve problems. This is not a "we write your code so you can just copy paste this" thing.

Comment: I understand, I do not want to copy and paste the answer, what I need is help me solve the probleama, and try what you mention but not working.
What if I say the winning lottery numbers ... But do not say what country? You would be helping?

Comment: Put `$data["customer_info"] = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($this->customer->getId())`into the index function, leave header.tpl as is. Not really that hard.

Comment: Ok, go back, just edit the question, that is what I have and also get the error ...

Comment: What about using `$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();` in header.php and using `echo $customer_firstname` in header.tpl?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: customer_firstname in.. :( Which may be? I start to frustrate, I find nothing in google ...

Answer (score 0):

Adds: `$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();` in `header.php`

You may be something:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
```

Displays the name eg in `header.tpl`: `<?php echo $customer_firstname ?>`

Login to your store manager: go to extensions, modifications and upgrade (button top right).

Ready!